# WMI enumerate users remotely. Only local users are returned and domain users are not

Tags: c#, wmi, remote-access

When running the WQL query `Select * from Win32_GroupUser` (namespace: root\cimv2) in computer A locally, I receive all users with groups, including the ones in Domain/Active Directory. But when running the same query from computer B to computer A remotely, I receive only part of users (local users of computer A, but the Domain/AD users are not returned). Is this some permission issue? Maybe there is some configuration for WMI to allow see domain users remotely?

Comment: Did you set `ImpersationLevel` to `Impersonate`?

Comment: Yes, the Impersonation Level is set to Impersonate.

Comment: I'd ask yourself why you're using WMI for this. There are much faster and easier ways to get user and group information from active directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally what I discovered is that you can't have that information from a remote computer. But as the question is about Domain/AD users and for connecting to remote computer the local computer has to be in the same Domain as well, that means the information about Domain/AD users can be retrieved without connecting to the remote machine, but against the local computer.

The solution is to run the query against local computer.